# How do I delete old projects in Google Code?

Tags: google-code

The Google Code service is shut down now, but the projects are still browsable. For my own reasons I want to delete these projects, but I can't delete this project in the administration console! The console displays the following:

> Project read-only 
>   This project is currently read-only. You may not make changes to it at this time.
>
> If you wish to delete this project, set up a redirection URL, or perform any other sort of administrative action, please contact google-code-shutdown@google.com.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy8Tw.png)

https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ReadOnlyTransition

Comment: i have send a email to google-code-shutdown@google.com yesterday, they have deleted the old project for me. they are good people.^_^

Comment: Nice ! You should create an answer to this question and accept :)

Comment: ok, I have just done it.